# plot Gráfico Eixo X com Data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Galera,

Tenho um gráfico e gostaria de colocar no eixo X a Data

Estava assim:

```
xAxis: {
    tickColor: 'transparent',
    tickDecimals: 2
},
```

Coloquei assim:

```
renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'}
```

Mas ele não forma, aparece assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu PHP está com o seguinte retorno:

```
{"visits":[[1496372400,"4435"],[1496631600,"4446"],[1496804400,"4462"],[1497236400,"4508"]],"returning_visitors":[[1496372400,"29222"],[1496631600,"29496"],[1496804400,"29733"],[1497236400,"30232"]],"extra":[[1496372400,"33657"],[1496631600,"33942"],[1496804400,"34195"],[1497236400,"34740"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

tente utilizar o comando date no PHP. Ex.:

```
date('Y/m/d', $variavel_data);
```

Comment: Esta resposta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo. Por favor, se possível e se esta for uma solução ao problema, explique melhor como você o resolveu. O código pode ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários pode não ser.